# Google Guice inject Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()

Tags: java, guice

My class uses an ScheduledExecutorService which it got by calling Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() until now.

Now, I want to inject it via Guice but I don't know how, because I don't get the instance vom ScheduledExecutorservice via a constructor call.

Can you help?

Comment: Implement Provider<ScheduledExecutorService>: bind(ScheduledExecutorService.class).toProvider(Executors::newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor);

Comment: doesn't the parameter of toProvider directly point to the implementation how to get the ScheduledExecutorService? Why do I have to additionally implement the Provider ?